# Decompile class file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiling, jad, jadclipse

I have configured the **JadClipse** plugin in Eclipse Kepler. I can decompile any class within a jar in eclipse. But how can I decompile a class, that is not in a jar, in eclipse?

Just like in command prompt the `jad -sjava HelloWorld.class` command decompiles a standalone class(that is not within a jar file), how can I achieve this in eclipse?

**EDIT**

I added a standalone class file to my project build path using `Add External Class Folder`. Now if I hit F3, it is not decompiling. Rather it is showing `Resource not found`.

Comment: What is stopping you to open that class file in eclipse ?

Comment: How do I view the class file in eclipse? I only see the .java files

Comment: Can you do open file > open file and then choose your class file.

Comment: If I do that it says, "The Class File Viewer cannot handle the given input"

Comment: Please see the Edit section.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add that class file to you build path and try to open it. That should work.

Comment: Please see the EDIT section in my question